# How to use Arduino as RC Receiver

Tags: drone

I want to use Arduino as my RC receiver. I will generate PPM signal from Arduino. Then I will send generated signal to my OpenPilot CC3D. I fetched following image from OpenPilot GCS. The diagram shows to use input 6.

[image]
Following is the image of my CC3D. The cable colors does not correspond to each other.

[image]

Which input cable should I connect to Arduino?
How should I connect black(ground) and red(5V) cables to Arduino:

Answer (score 2):

EDIT this answer explains how you can put a Arduino between a (1 ppm pin per channel) RC receiver and a RC receptor. This allows for smart features (like autonomous control with RC overrule, or sensor based corrections,..)
It seems it is not the question of op.

What you want is easy but there are some pitfalls.
I can make a long story short by these links

http://rcarduino.blogspot.be/2012/01/how-to-read-rc-receiver-with.html
http://rcarduino.blogspot.be/2012/01/how-to-read-rc-receiver-with_20.html
http://rcarduino.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-read-multiple-rc-channels-draft.html

if you are serious about RC this may be of your interest to
http://rcarduino.blogspot.be/2012/01/how-to-read-rc-receiver-with_25.html

I also converted this info in a library you can find here:
https://github.com/jantje/ArduinoLibraries/tree/master/RCLib

And for stackexchange policy here the hightlights.
If I look at the picture you added you have a 6 channel ppm receiver. Each ppm channel you want to read must be connected to a interrupt enabled pin of your arduino (The drawbacks of software enabled interrupt pin is another discussion).
The high time of the ppm tells how high or low your lever is on the remote control.
You can then have arduino do with this info what you want. For instance use the servo library to generate a ppm signal out to servo's and ppm driven motors.

Comment: Your answer addresses a problem opposite of that in the question.  This is not about reading an RC receiver but about creating one.  The PWM(s) are outputs, not inputs.

Comment: I was wondering what was actually asked. It just shows the quality of the average question.  My answer is actually RC in RC out. and it is PPM not PWM. The servo library creates PPM

Comment: Radio PPM is not servo PWM

Comment: @ChrisStratton is right. I want to use Arduino as RC receiver. I will generate PPM signal from Arduino. Then I will send generated signal to my OpenPilot CC3D.

Comment: @jantje There are 6 channels. But only 1 of them is used as PPM channel. As shown in the image which I fetched from OpenPilot GCS software, the PPM channel is shown as 8th pin.

Comment: @Halil Your question is still not clear to me. As this is a Arduino forum and not a aviation forum I think it would be a good idea to place arduino in the middle and explain what your input is and what the output is you want to achieve.Just my 2 cent. From what I understand now your question is: "How can I -using a arduino- mimic a rc receiver compatible with a openPilot CC3D" (and if that is the question I can't answer it )

Comment: @jantje I think you didn't fully read the question. Please review again the last 2 lines which is below the photo. I am not asking how to mimic rc receiver using arduino in this post. I am asking how to connect CC3D controller to Arduino